# How can I find why is my pickled data so large?

Tags: python, optimization, size, pickle

I've got a python (3.1 if that matters) application that pickles data for another process to consume, and exchange them over network connections. For some reason, some exchange are unexpectedly large ... I can make sense of some of the pickled data and figure out what's transmitted, but there remain a large blob of apparently binary data which I fail to explain to myself, such as redundant strings or large chunk of binary data.

Do you know whether there is a wireshark plugin that could assist me with that task, or another process you'd recommend to someone trying to figure out what more should have been `=None`'d before the object is transmitted over the connection ?

```
RouteDirect
q.).q.}q.(X...._RouteDirect__dst_nodeq.cnode
Node
q.).q.}q.(X...._Node__status_upq.NX...._Node__neighbourhoodq.NX...._Node__sendq.NX
..._Node__cpeq
cequation
CPE
q.).q.}q^M(X...._CPE__dim_countq.}q.X...._CPE__internal_nodesq.]q.ubX...._Node__major_stateq.NX...._Node__partition_idq.G?.$:..4.    X...._Node__name_idq.cnodeid
NameID
q.).q.}q.X^M..._NameID__nameq.X....checkq.sbX...._Node__dispatcherq.NX...._Node__pendingq.]q.cmessages
```

^ I can make sense of that: RouteDirect, CPE and NameID are classes in my program.

v I'm more surprised about this: there shouldn't be that much "plain binary" data in the exchange, although Iproto, Tflags, Isrc and Idst are strings contained within those data

```
 q0).q1}q2(X...._Range__maxq3X....1f40q4X...._Range__min_includedq5.X...._Range__max_includedq6.X...._
 Range__minq7h4ubX...._Component__dimensionq8h'ubh&).q9}q:h)X....Tflagsq;sbh+).q<}q=(h..h/h0).q>}q?            
 (h3X....02q@h5.h6.h7h@ubh8h9ubh&).qA}qBh)X....IprotoqCsbh+).qD}qE(h..h/h0).qF}qG(h3X...

 .06qHh5.h6.h7hHubh8hAubh&).qI}qJh)X....IsrcqKsbh+).qL}qM(h..h/h0).qN}qO(h3X....7d59d8faqPh5.h6.
 h7hPubh8hIubh&).qQ}qRh)X....IdstqS    
 sbh+).qT}qU(h..h/h0).qV}qW(h3X....00001011qXh5.h6.h7hXubh8hQubh&).qY}qZh)X....Tsrcq[sbh+).q\}q]         
 (h..h/h0).q^}q_(h3X....0bcfq`h5.h6.h7h`ubh8hYubusbX....
```

v and this is *really* perplexing.

```
qt).qu}qv(X...._LookupRequest__keyqwh!).qx}qyh$}qz(h&).q{}q|h)h*sbh+).q}}q~(h..h/h0).q.}q.
(h3h4h5.h6.h7h4ubh8h{ubh&).q.}q.h)h;sbh+).q.}q.(h..h/h0).q.}q.(h3h@h5.h6.h7h@ubh8h.ubh&).q.}q.h)hCsbh+).q.}q.(h..h/h0).q.}q.
(h3hHh5.h6.h7hHubh8h.ubh&).q.}q.h)hKsbh+).q.}q.(h..h/h0).q.}q.(h3hPh5.h6.h7hPubh8h.ubh&).q.}q.h)hSsbh+).q.}q.(h..h/h0).q.}q.
(h3hXh5.h6.h7hXubh8h.ubh&).q.}q.h)h[sbh+).q.}q.(h..h/h0).q.}q.
(h3h`h5.h6.h7h`ubh8h.ubusbX...._LookupRequest__nonceq.G?...u...X...._LookupRequest__fromq.h.).q.}q.(h.Nh.Nh.Nh
h.).q.}q.(h.}q.
```

What puzzle me the most is that it seems too regular to be e.g. mere floats/ints in binary. It has some affinity for numbers and [shub] and lot of 'isolated' `q`'s ... which reminds me more of machine code. or is it just my eyes ?

example of pickling support in the `Node` class, 
    #
    # Define special pickling behaviour.

```
def __getstate__(self):
    """Indicate witch fields should be pickled."""
    state = copy.copy(self.__dict__)

    # 'state' is a shallow copy: don't modify objects' content
    # Make transients fields point to nothing
    state['_Node__dispatcher'] = None
    state['_Node__send'] = None
    state['_Node__neighbourhood'] = None
    state['_Node__status_up'] = None
    state['_Node__data_store'] = None
    state['_Node__running_op'] = None
    state['_Node__major_state'] = None

    return state
```

Many other objects (e.g. `CPE`, `RouteDirect`) have no `__getstate__` method. I'd love it if there was some technique that doesn't require me to crawl through all constructors of all classes, of course.

Comment: How does your pickling code look like?

Comment: Without your pickling and network code, it's harder to figure out what's going on. You could try saving your pickled data to file for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Evert: true. I'm looking for guidance on "how could I assess why" more than the "why" itself, actually.

Comment: I'd also save the data chunks until there is a large one which looks suspicious in the way you describe; then I'd unpickle that chunk in the interactive console and have a look at it (`dir()` etc.).  I wouldn't be too surprised to find just some references to other objects than the main one.  Ah, to find out what gets created during unpickling, I'd insert some debug output in the `__init__`s of all possible classes.

Comment: and since it's bytecode, it make sense that there's no automated analyzer in wireshark as you'd find for e.g. HTTP or SNMP ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, reading /usr/lib/python3.1/pickle.py code at least make one point less obscure: output of pickling is indeed some bytecode for some interpreter, with push/pop pairs that explains the regular patterns seen.

```
BINPUT         = b'q'   # store stack top in memo; index is 1-byte arg
BINGET         = b'h'   # push item from memo on stack; index is 1-byte arg
EMPTY_TUPLE    = b')'   # push empty tuple
MARK           = b'('   # push special markobject on stack
```

etc.

Following @Alfe's comment, I captured raw traffic using wireshark "follow TCP stream" and "save as ..." features, then used

```
x=pickle.load(open("wirecapture.bin","rb"))
```

and used Python evaluator to get a better understanding of what was there. Esp. using

```
len(pickle.dump(x.my_field))
```

for all fields reported by `dir(x)` allowed me to pin-point the over-sized field. Unfortunately, I couldn't get

```
for y in dir(x):
   print("%s: %iKb"%(y,len(pickle.dumps(x[y])/1024))
```

properly working (`x[y]` wasn't the valid way to extract `x.my_field` when y == `'my_field'` >_< )

Comment: for p in vars(x).keys():
...    print("%s:%s"%(p,vars(x)[p]))
will help for the next time ...